# Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Tags: java, android, xml

Can anyone assist me in figuring out the cause for this android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup error? I've spent several hours looking for clues online but none of the issues highlighted by other users has led to a solution for me.

```
public class LandingPageActivity extends Activity {@
    Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final String packageName = this.getClass().getPackage().getName();
        final Context context = this;

        // ScrollView
        ViewGroup contentView = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.activity_landing_page, null);

        // Layout containing Buttons
        ViewGroup g = (ViewGroup) contentView.getChildAt(0);
        int count = g.getChildCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            Button btn = (Button) g.getChildAt(i);
            final String text = btn.getText().toString();
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {@
                Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        Class c = Class.forName(packageName + "." + text);
                        startActivity(new Intent(context, c));
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(e), 5000).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        setContentView(contentView);
    }
}
```

activity_landing_page.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Click Button" />

</ScrollView>
```

Error Log

```
01-22 22:05:45.068: E/AndroidRuntime(29628): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 22:05:45.068: E/AndroidRuntime(29628): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.clarkben.android.footballinsight/com.clarkben.android.footballinsight.LandingPageActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
01-22 22:05:45.068: E/AndroidRuntime(29628):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
01-22 22:05:45.068: E/AndroidRuntime(29628):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
01-22 22:05:45.068: E/AndroidRuntime(29628):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-22 22:05:45.068: E/AndroidRuntime(29628):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
01-22 22:05:45.068: E/AndroidRuntime(29628):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-22 22:05:45.068: E/AndroidRuntime(29628):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-22 22:05:45.068: E/AndroidRuntime(29628):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-22 22:05:45.068: E/AndroidRuntime(29628):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 22:05:45.068: E/AndroidRuntime(29628):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-22 22:05:45.068: E/AndroidRuntime(29628):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-22 22:05:45.068: E/AndroidRuntime(29628):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-22 22:05:45.068: E/AndroidRuntime(29628):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-22 22:05:45.068: E/AndroidRuntime(29628): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
01-22 22:05:45.068: E/AndroidRuntime(29628):    at com.clarkben.android.footballinsight.LandingPageActivity.onCreate(LandingPageActivity.java:27)
01-22 22:05:45.068: E/AndroidRuntime(29628):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
01-22 22:05:45.068: E/AndroidRuntime(29628):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-22 22:05:45.068: E/AndroidRuntime(29628):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
01-22 22:05:45.068: E/AndroidRuntime(29628):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: have you tried cleaning the project and rebuilding it?

Comment: Yes I have tried that

Comment: `ViewGroup g = (ViewGroup) contentView.getChildAt(0);`  The first child of your layout (in fact, the only child) is a `Button`.  What makes you expect it to be a `ViewGroup`?

Comment: `// Layout containing Buttons` what makes you think that ?

Comment: Thank you! I had forgotten to put the Button inside a Linear Layout which was the intended child of the view. Solved.

Comment: Check my Answer, i think you could set up an activity with much less code.

Answer (score 2):

instead of using `getChildAt()` you should be directly addressing your components like this:

```
findViewById(R.id.button1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to:

```
// ScrollView
ViewGroup contentView = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(context)
    .inflate(R.layout.activity_landing_page, null);

// Layout containing Buttons
int count = contentView.getChildCount();

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    Button btn = (Button) contentView.getChildAt(i);
    final String text = btn.getText().toString();
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {@
        Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                Class c = Class.forName(packageName + "." + text);
                startActivity(new Intent(context, c));
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(e), 5000).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
setContentView(contentView);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you are inflating your view, i dont know why you would use Viewgroup instead of the actual class. It also clarifies which object from your Layout you are accessing

```
ScrollView  contentView = (ScrollView) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_landing_page, null);
```

bseides that, you do know that you can actually just set the xml as contentView? See end of post

Inline the count, makes the code shorter since it doesnt look like you are using that int again.

```
for (int i = 0; i < contentView.getChildCount(); i++) {
    Button btn = (Button) contentView.getChildAt(i);
    final String text = btn.getText().toString();
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                Class c = Class.forName(packageName + "." + text);
                startActivity(new Intent(context, c));
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(e), 5000).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
setContentView(contentView);
```

Besides that you could access the Button like this:

```
contentView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

but i assume you are going to add a lot more buttons, even tho i dont think that it will look too good with just a massive amount of buttons.

**Another approach**

This is doing just the same as your code, but significantly shorter.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_landing_page):

Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            Class c = Class.forName(packageName + "." + text);
            startActivity(new Intent(context, c));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(e), 5000).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your good tips. You're right I have more buttons to add. I actually made a very simple layout xml for the purposes of simplifying this question and not getting everyone to read loads of code. The actual xml page has many buttons in a relative layout.